# [ros2] Test for correct node_name and namespace

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing integration test cases for my ROS service. Please see the sample code snippet below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from threading import Thread
import unittest

from example_interfaces.srv import AddTwoInts
import launch
import launch_ros
import launch_ros.actions
import launch_testing.actions
import pytest
import rclpy


@pytest.mark.rostest
def generate_test_description():
    minimal_service_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='examples_rclpy_minimal_service',
        namespace='my_namespace',
        executable='service_member_function',
        name='minimal_service',
    )
    return (
        launch.LaunchDescription(
            [
                minimal_service_node,
                launch_testing.actions.ReadyToTest(),
            ]
        ),
        {
            'minimal_service': minimal_service_node,
        },
    )


class TestMinimalService(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        rclpy.init()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        rclpy.shutdown()

    def setUp(self):
        self.node = rclpy.create_node('test_minimal_service')

        # the following line is a pseudo code
        self.alll_node_names_and_namespaces = rclpy.get_node_names_and_namespaces()

        self.spin_thread = Thread(target=rclpy.spin, args=(self.node,))
        self.spin_thread.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.node.destroy_node()

    def test_node_namespaces(self):
        # test whether node is having with correct namespace
        namespaces = [namespace for _, namespace in self.alll_node_names_and_namespaces]
        self.assertIn('my_namespace', namespaces)

    def test_node_name(self):
        # test whether node is having with correct name
        node_names = [node_name for node_name, _ in self.alll_node_names_and_namespaces]
        self.assertIn('minimal_service', node_names)
```

### Question

How to test whether my node is having with correct name and namespace?

### Additional Info

Below is the workspace structure:

```
.
├── build
├── install
├── log
└── src
    └── minimal_service
        ├── CHANGELOG.rst
        ├── examples_rclpy_minimal_service
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── service_member_function.py
        ├── package.xml
        ├── README.md
        ├── resource
        │   └── examples_rclpy_minimal_service
        ├── setup.cfg
        ├── setup.py
        └── test
            ├── test_copyright.py
            ├── test_flake8.py
            ├── test_pep257.py
            └── test_service_member_function.py  <- This is the newly added file
```

The package `minimal_service` has been taken from [ros2/examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/foxy/rclpy/services/minimal_service).

### Other Info

- Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Installation type: binaries
- Version or commit hash: ROS Foxy
- DDS implementation: Default
- Client library: rclpy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404322/%5Bros2%5D-test-for-correct-node_name-and-namespace/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2022-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're real close:

```
self.alll_node_names_and_namespaces = self.node.get_node_names_and_namespaces()
```

which returns a list of tuples such as: `[('test', '/'), ('talker', '/my/test/ns')]`. After that, everything else looks right.

If you're still not getting any data, you may not be giving the node enough time to actually accumulate discovery information. You may consider replacing your thread with an `rclpy.spin_once(self.node, timeout_sec=1.0)` to block for at most a second, giving the node some time to discover other nodes.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2022-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-09**:
Thanks for your answer. I tried, but it failed. Please see shortened log below:

```
$ launch_test src/minimal_service/test/test_service_member_function.py 
test_node_name (test_service_member_function.TestMinimalService) ... 
FAIL
test_node_namespaces (test_service_member_function.TestMinimalService) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_node_name (test_service_member_function.TestMinimalService)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError: 'minimal_service' not found in ['test_minimal_service']

======================================================================
FAIL: test_node_namespaces (test_service_member_function.TestMinimalService)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError: 'my_namespace' not found in ['/']

--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2022-08-09**:
Three things:

1. You need to add some sort of spin prior to getting the node names and types. I did the following, but there's probably sleeker ways to do it:

   ```
    def setUp(self):
        self.node = rclpy.create_node('test_minimal_service')
        rclpy.spin_once(self.node, timeout_sec=2.0)
        self.alll_node_names_and_namespaces = self.node.get_node_names_and_namespaces()
   ```
2. You'll need to do `self.assertIn('/my_namespace', namespaces)` instead of `self.assertIn('my_namespace', namespaces)`
3. I could only get these tests to run via `colcon test`. Running them through clion's test runner wouldn't work for me. (in case you're running it some other way.)

With those three things, these tests work for me.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-10**:
Thanks a lot. 1. I used `launch_test` with the modifications you suggested, and it worked. 2. I used the `colcon test`, it showed endless warnings, and I certainly had no idea about the status of my test cases. May I request you to look at the logs in [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/uUiSnK03), please? 3. It seems that `self.spin_thread` is not required in this case. Using `rclpy.spin_once` before calling `get_node_names_and_namespaces` apparently enough.

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2022-08-10**:
The pytest warnings about pathlib I usually just ignore... But it seems that those have been fixed in galactic, Cause I'm not seeing them there. When using `colcon test` I'll look at the log/latest_test/example_rclpy_minimal_service/streams.log file to get a better understanding of what's going on.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-13**:
The `colcon test` shows similar warnings in ROS Galactic in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS as well. I checked the "streams.log" file and can not find any information about my test case "test_node_namespaces". So I am sharing the [streams.log](https://pastebin.com/H5yRqBDN) file and [test_service_member_function.py](https://pastebin.com/43f88uh7) for your reference. BTW, in the same topic, may I request you to [look at here, please](https://answers.ros.org/question/404321/ros2-test-is-not-finishing-its-execution/)? My goal is to write integration test cases for a ROS service. Thank you very much.